# Django doesn't load static files from React

Tags: reactjs, django

Django gives 404 error for static files. I created a Django and React projects in separate folders following this tutorial but created the React project with Vite https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYKRAXIio28 . Then brought React project as "frontend" into the Django. Ran `npm run build` which created below inside frontend folder.

```
│   index.html
│   vite.svg
│
└───assets
        index-757929e7.js
        index-a9bba2ed.css
```

Added `BASE_DIR / 'frontend/dist'` in Django settings.py file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "DIRS": [
            BASE_DIR / 'frontend/dist'
        ],
    },
]
```

Added this below that for static files npm created.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'frontend/dist/assets'
]
```

Added `path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))` to urls.py

When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000 it successfully loads the html file but not the css or js. I'm getting this error in the browser.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/assets/index-a9bba2ed.css' because its 

MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

The html file in frontend/dist folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-757929e7.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-a9bba2ed.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `STATIC_URL`? Have you used the `static` template tag?

Comment: @Dauros STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Here is an example how to refer to static files from django template https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files